# Instantiating a variadic member function template of a class template

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

How can I instantiate a variadic member function template of a class template in separate `.cpp` file? Say, given an above class template in a set of files: `a.hpp` with definition of interface, `a_impl.hpp` with implementation and `a.cpp` with instantiation, - which includes each previous in the chain sequentially, but only the first is visible to the user of the class (as opposed to the developer).

Especially interested in case of an empty parameter pack.

Answer (score 2):

```
template <class A>
struct AA
{
  template<class Z, class... Q>
  void aa(double, Q... q) {};
};

template void AA<int>::aa<char>(double);
template void AA<int>::aa<char, char*>(double, char*);
template void AA<int>::aa<char, char*, char**>(double, char*, char**);
```

Note that in your setup only the "developer" can instantiate (one needs to see the implementation in order to be able to instantiate).

Comment: But is it obligatory the presence of the `Z` template parameter?

Comment: No it's just an example, it shows that you can have a template parameters not mentioned in the function signature.

Comment: Automatic template parameters deduction will not work in this case, isn't it?