# Explicitly instantiating variadic constructor: template-id does not match any template declaration

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, explicit-instantiation

I'm trying to [explicitly instantiate a variadic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691615/instantiating-a-variadic-member-function-template-of-a-class-template) constructor. This minimal example to [print all arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339789/how-to-call-a-function-on-all-variadic-template-args?noredirect=1&lq=1) causes the same error I'm seeing on MinGW-w64 on 64 bit Win 7 with GCC 5.3.

```
struct stf {
 template<typename... Args> stf(Args&&... args){
  using expand_type = int[];
  expand_type{(print(args), 0)... };
 }
};

//error on next line:
//template-id 'stf<char*, char*>' for 'stf::stf(char*, char*)'
//does not match any template declaration
template stf::stf<char*,char*>(char*,char*);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's ignore the parameter pack, for one moment:

```
template<typename Arg> stf(Arg &&args)
```

Pop quiz: which instantiation matches the above template. Is it:

```
template<char *> stf(char *);
```

or

```
template<char *> stf(char *&&);
```

?

If you substitute `char *` everywhere the template type appears in the template, you'll obviously end up with the second version as the right answer.

Therefore, the correct template instantiation must be:

```
template stf::stf<char*,char*>(char* &&,char* &&);
```